# How (and Where) to store downloadable commerce files outside the file system..?

Tags: commerce, users

I’m building a Drupal Commerce site and am selling downloadable mp3’s. It was recommend that the downloadable commerce files should be kept outside the sites file directory. I’ve tried setting this directory in the admin in 2 places, as separate attempts:

First i created a folder called commerce_files and set it one level up from the Drupal install

Then i tried referencing this folder in 2 places (as 2 separate attempts)

```
Configuration->Media->File System 
Configuration->Product Variation Types->My MP3 Content type->File
```

Neither worked.

When searching the internet for this topic nothing much is coming up. Does anyone here have any insight or info on this topic? it would be appreciated, thanks

Or maybe i was misled and it is perfectly acceptable to store within the file system, using the Config->Media->Private Folder setting in the admin as i have been doing....?

FYI - have gotten almost no responses when posting the Drupal commerce.org,

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the "Private file system path" to be outside your Drupal installation by changing it in the admin/config/media/file-system. and you configure your commerce files there. this should do the trick. either way Drupal do not provide direct url access to the private files.

Comment: i tried that, or so i thought. will try again.